# Create a column that increases at a constant rate using the tidyverse

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr

I have a time series of population, and I want to compare how the population grows in relation to some growth rate. Therefore, I'm trying to create a column that multiplies my initial population value by some constant growth rate, and then multiply that value by the same constant growth rate, etc. etc. I can't just multiply by the growth rate using mutate because it won't use the previous value.

Note: I've answered my own question below, but have provided this as a resource to others. If there are other ways of accomplishing the same goal, I'd be interested to here about them.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)

growth_rate <- 0.05 # percent

# the "estimated" column is what I want.
df <- tibble(year = seq(2000, 2005, by = 1),
             population = seq(1, 2, length = 6),
             estimated = c(1.00, 1.05, 1.10, 1.16, 1.22, 1.28))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do we need `purrr::accumulate` when same thing can be achieved using simple formula as:

```
library(tidyverse)
growth_rate <- 0.05 # percent
df %>% mutate(Calculated = first(estimated)*((1+growth_rate)^(row_number()-1)))
# # A tibble: 6 x 4
# year population estimated Calculated
# <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>
# 1  2000       1.00      1.00       1.00
# 2  2001       1.20      1.05       1.05
# 3  2002       1.40      1.10       1.10
# 4  2003       1.60      1.16       1.16
# 5  2004       1.80      1.22       1.22
# 6  2005       2.00      1.28       1.28
```

**EDIT**

@Frank had already pointed out with `comment` using compound interest rate to calculate `growth_rate` in one of answer above.

Answer (score 2):

Use `purrr::accumulate` to recursively multiply your initial value with your growth rate, and keep the intermediate values. Here, `.x` is your accumulating value. See the [documentation](http://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/accumulate.html) for more information.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

# alteratively, load the tidyverse 
# library(tidyverse)

growth_rate <- 0.05 # percent

df <- tibble(year = seq(2000, 2005, by = 1),
             population = seq(1, 2, length = 6),
             estimated = c(1.00, 1.05, 1.10, 1.16, 1.22, 1.28))

df <- df %>%
  mutate(with_purr = accumulate(population, ~ .x * (1 + growth_rate)))

df
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#>    year population estimated with_purr
#>   <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1 2000.       1.00      1.00      1.00
#> 2 2001.       1.20      1.05      1.05
#> 3 2002.       1.40      1.10      1.10
#> 4 2003.       1.60      1.16      1.16
#> 5 2004.       1.80      1.22      1.22
#> 6 2005.       2.00      1.28      1.28
```

Comment: Maybe you know this already, but if your growth rate is constant, as here, then `1.05^(row_number()-1)`, and if not `cumprod(growth_rate_vector)`...

Comment: Wouldn't this make more sense if you had stipulated the `growth_rate` was 1.05 at the outset?